# what are disadvantages of using ":xpath" attribute to identify an object using Watir?

Tags: watir

I am using `:xpath` attribute frequently to identify an element for my automation scripts using Watir and found it really amazing. It is least changing attribute so less work to maintain automated scripts.. off course for those elements which can't be identified otherwise easily through :id, :name, :value attributes..

I am bit concerned to take some expert advise before building so many automated scripts using :xpath.

1. What is disadvantage of using :xpath to identify an object using Watir?
2. Do `:xpath` value of an element will be same in IE, Chrome and FF?when

Is there anything else important i should be aware about using :xpath?

Thanks

Comment: Anecdotally, I'd think using `:xpath` as a locator (as opposed to `:id`) would be slower.  But I've never benchmarked it.  It would be interesting to know if there's a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

The xpath should always be the same in all browsers.

The problem with using xpath is that it is the easiest locator to break, as the locator for the element is dependant on nothing else in that xpath changing.  e.g. if you are locating a results table on a page using an xpath and at a later date another table gets added above the table, then the xpath will be broken and your tests will fail until you update the xpath.  If that table was located using an id then adding the second table wouldn't break anything as the new table would have a different id.

If the pages you're working on don't have id's and it isn't an option to add some/ ask for some to be added then remember that in watir you can use multiple locators.

e.g. @browser.table(class: 'results_table', text: /Original results table/)

This is a silly example but hopefully it illustrates the point.  If there are cases when using multiple locators still won't work for any reason, then I would look into using css selectors instead of xpath as you should be able to achieve the same things but it will be less brittle.

The issue of how often tests break isn't too important in a small test suite, especially if you're the only one working on the tests.  However, a couple of years from now when you have hundreds of tests to maintain and two or three people sharing the codebase you can end up spending longer fixing old tests that you spend writing the new ones.  It's worth doing anything you reasonably can to minimise this as you go along as doing a rewrite later will always take longer.

Hopefully some of this helps!